# Financial Data from FinViz using IMPORTHTML

Tags: google-finance

I am trying to export financial data - Net Income, for instance - using FINVIZ on this page: https://elite.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=A&ty=c&p=d&b=1

I am able to grab other information from this page using the following formula:
=index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="& $A2,"table",8),3,4)
using GOOGLE SHEETS

This doesn't work for the financial information because I can't determine what the table number is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems that table is generated with javascript so would need to get using json

Comment: can i use json with IMPORTHTML or is that only used with Python? Thanks so much.

Comment: you can use json with google app script as shown in the example I provided. I am guessing Python as well. I have not played with Python yet, it is on my to-do list to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering your comment question here as it has a script example using json in google app script

```
function growthEstimate(code){
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code+'/analysis'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  return data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteSummaryStore.earningsTrend.trend[4].growth.fmt
}
function testGrowth(){
  Logger.log(growthEstimate('AAPL'))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this in my file and got this error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'earningsTrend' of undefined
growthEstimate @ Jason Sample.gs:6

Comment: Running the script as written, I get 17.93% in my log.